# operator overloading in Cuda

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I successfully created an operator+ between two float4 by doing :

```
__device__ float4 operator+(float4 a, float4 b) {
 // ...
}
```

However, if in addition, I want to have an  operator+ for uchar4, by doing the same thing with uchar4, i get the following error:
"error: more than one instance of overloaded function "operator+" has "C" linkage" "

I get a similar error message when I declare multiple functions with the same name but different arguments.
So, two questions :

- **Polymorphism** : Is-it possible to have multiple functions with the same name and different arguments in Cuda ? If so, why do I have this error message ?
- **operator+ for float4** : it seems that this feature is already included by including "cutil_math.h", but when I include that (`#include <cutil_math.h>`) it complains that there is no such file or directory... anything particular I should do ? Note: I am using pycuda, which is a cuda for python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the "has "C" linkage" in the error. You are compiling your code with C linkage (pyCUDA does this by default to circumvent symbol mangling issues). C++ can't support multiple definitions of the same function name using C linkage.

The solution is to compile code without automatically generated "extern C", and explicitly specify C linkage only for kernels. So your code would looks something like:

```
__device__ float4 operator+(float4 a, float4 b) { ... };

extern "C"
__global__ void kernel() { };
```

rather than the standard pyCUDA emitted:

```
extern "C" 
{
     __device__ float4 operator+(float4 a, float4 b) { ... };

     __global__ void kernel() { };
}
```

`pycuda.compiler.SourceModule` has an option `no_extern_c`  which can be used to control whether `extern "C"` is emitted by the just in time compilation system or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense! I'll try that asap. But how do we change how pyCuda compiles the code?

Comment: @WhitAngl: Sorry I forgot to add that in the answer. Have a look at my edit.